# Product review disapeared from tab

Tags: product, products, review, additional-information

I don't know what happened, maybe you'll be able to help me.

I've copied `Reviews` folder from the `Base` to my custom theme and sudenly the review disapeared from tabs...

Tryed to undo it and still the review section is not visible. It shows's the tab and title of the tab, but the content is missing.

Any ideas?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its really hard to debug your issue without having access to source files. However this suggestion might help you.

- First check which design package is been being used from here `System -> Configuration -> Design -> Package`.
- Then go to the package folder under `app/design/frontend/package_name/default/template` and copy **review** folder if exist.
- Then paste **review** folder in your custom theme template folder.

Note: make sure to clear Magento cache after this.

Comment: hey, thanks for tryed, but answer to all above is YES. The problem is that it was working ok until I've copied and pasted the Review folder from Base to my custom theme folder.

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas so there were no review folder in your custom theme before you copied it from base folder?

Comment: @Abiidred1 yes, that is correct.

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas have you tried to delete the review folder and clear or disable magento cache? or any other cache in that matter.

Comment: Yes, multiple times...

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas Try to remove magento cache folders under var/cache as well.

Comment: Did it, even deleted the review's from custom theme and again cleaned the var/cache and nothing... Now logically it should appear as it did before, but it doesn't. Reviews only exist's in base and still not showing on front end.

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas did you add any xml changes to any file under **layout** folder when adding Reviews folder from base?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18840/discussion-between-arturas-strazdas-and-aboodred1).

Comment: This is what is strange.. I did nothing in xml file, nothing..

Comment: Thank you @Aboodred1, you gave me an idea with the XML files and I don't know what was happening, but the thing is I build my theme based on RWD, when copied the files from Base to my theme it didn't work but then deleted them and copied the files from RWD to my theme and it now show's again. Thanks a lot for the help. !!!!!

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas finally some action :D

Comment: Omg, I've been stuck with it for hours.. Rookie mistake I suppose... Thanks for everything :)

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas sounds good, feel free to mark it as resolved issue.